# Web Service Call InfoPath 2010

Tags: 2010, infopath

I am literally fighting infopath right now. I am trying to populate MySites information into infopath via web call.

Here are my steps:

Data (Get External Data) > From Web Service > SOAP Web Service > Entered the location of the SOAP Web service > Selected GetuserprofilebyName > Home > Calculated Value (Controls) > fx > Insert Field or Group > Change to new data source > value > filter value > name = FirstName and ok.

When I hit Preview thats when it all goes wrong. I get error messages from Infopath saying I  "Some external data was not retrieved. The form will load without the requested data" Show Detials >> "The SOAP response indicates that an error occurred on the srver. Operation Failure ---> Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation"

**Then in the SharePoint list I get the error:**

An error occurred while trying to connect to a Web service.

An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server.

Log ID:5566

Correlation ID:04d6d068-dc49-41c7-8404-4400d9a20fcb

InfoPath design checker says Unsupported HTML, Information will not be shown to user...arg!

Answer (score 0):

I think this site could give your more light on the issue. It is a dedicated info path dev center.

http://www.infopathdev.com/search/SearchResults.aspx?q=Web+Service+Call+InfoPath+2010